# What is all the equipment used by the Russian imperial army?

Tags: identification, uniform, russian-empire

What is the equipment shown in this image?

[image: A Russian soldier standing in front of a military train]

I would like to know what the belts are and what some of the other equipment is and if you know where to buy them that would be helpful.

thank you to everyone and to the person that said to just look up Russian ww1 equipment I have done that a lot and cant find half of the stuff I need

Comment: Your question would benefit from a little more detail about what you want to know.

Comment: The rifle, the blanket or the mess kit?

Comment: Not a blanket, greatcoat rolled up.

Comment: from when or where is the image? such pictures are at times made by people who have never even seen the real items.

Comment: Well that's a Mosin rifle, so we're looking at 1891 at the earliest. Most likely after 1907 judging by the uniform. Searching for "Russian army wwi equipment" on eBay or something should get you what you need.

Comment: Probably this helps : https://meshok.net/listing?good=14405&sort=cur_price&ut%5B%5D=ремень&way=desc . https://www.avito.ru/moskva_i_mo/kollektsionirovanie?q=ремень+риа . But i don't know about shipping, you should to ask the traider)

Comment: and this artical about equipment: https://topwar.ru/128533-100-let-russkoy-slavy-uniforma-i-snaryazhenie-pehoty-rossiyskoy-imperatorskoy-armii.html

Answer (score 6):

The image as presented is not a particularly good one one for gathering individual details about the gear being used, It is likely an artistic derivation of an image taken from the cover of the book [The Russian Army 1914–18 (Men-at-Arms)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1841763039) by Nik Cornish (Author), Andrei Karachtchouk (Illustrator)

[image]

If you can find a copy of this book it will likely be able to give you very specific details concerning the gear depicted.

(I was unable to locate a borrowable copy at archive.org.
But the Russian language re-issue of this book gives the following, translated back in to English:

> Private of the Life Guards Semyonov Regiment, 1914.
>
> In full summer marching uniform, this Guardsman represents what the British military attaché described as "the finest human material in Europe".
>
> On the cuffs of his jacket can be seen white lace ('galloon') indicating that he belongs to the 1st Guards Infantry Division, a blue bar on his chest, and the epaulettes bear the blue insignia of the 2nd Regiment of the Division. Only the Guards infantry was provided with satchels worn behind the back. behind their backs. It was a common practice to tuck the ends of the knapsack into the canteen ('bowler').

)

---

Another book which will give you many of the details you may be seeking would be [Imperial Russian Field Uniforms and Equipment 1907-1917](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764335227) by Johan Somers (Author)

This book is actually discussed (and quickly flipped through) on [a YouTube video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFD1cxR8HjU). This shows the variety of options which were produced for each particular item. The [video at 4:09](https://youtu.be/PFD1cxR8HjU?t=249) for instance shows the variety of **mess tins** which were produced. An item hanging of the belt on the soldiers left side in the OPs image is likely a **trenching tool**, a variety of which can be seen starting on the [video at 2:43](https://youtu.be/PFD1cxR8HjU?t=163). The books pages on the **rucksack** just visible on the soldiers back are [discussed at 6:00](https://youtu.be/PFD1cxR8HjU?t=360).

Typically I prefer to provide specific identification down to item model numbers, but these books demonstrate that there are many models of each item available, and the painting seems to be very generic, likely intentionally so to present a very *general* idea of the gear worn during the early 20th century Russian military. (If you are interested to watch another [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/esNyj5Qkl3U), a much larger youtube channel here has another discussion of Russian uniforms of this era.)

Comment: Note the rolled great coat is discussed in [this accepted answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/71373/16951) to another question.